# Bootstrap 3 keep mobile menu view across all device widths

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a relatively straight forward way to use the mobile menu style across all device widths? I didn't want to go hacking around in media queries in case I messed something up!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .navbar class with the .navbar-collapse class.

navbar-collapse display mobile style menu when the device width is under the value of @grid-float-breakpoint.

The default value is 768px.

You can customize Bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics).